# Получение прямого адреса функции

Tags: visual-c++, ассемблер, компиляция

Имею DLL, в ней нужно мне получить прямой адрес до функции (т.е. адрес самой первой ассемблерной инструкции функции) - пример:

Есть некая функция: 
`void RedrawCallback(float time, int intermission);`

Методами отладчика я выяснил что она находится по адресу 0x0b321780, теперь в дизассемблере я перехожу по этому адресу и вижу:

```
and ch, bl 
mov dh, 0D 
// ну и код функции далее...
```

Ну собственно это я и искал, тут всё верно.

А теперь я получаю адрес функции прямо из кода таким образом:

```
void* callback = &RedrawCallback;
```

Как я уже знаю, функция находится по адресу 0x0b321780, смотрю, что там в указателе и вижу что адрес там нифига не 0x0b321780, а 0x0b32111d.

После, лезу в дизассемблер, перехожу по неизвестному адресу из указателя и наблюдаю там очень интересную инструкцию:

```
jmp 0x0b321780 // адрес той самой функции
```

То есть, оператор взятия адреса дал мне адрес прыжка до функции, но не адрес первой инструкции функции. Почему, зачем? Это такие фичи компилятора? Как прямой адрес получить? Не, ну я понимаю что можно для взятия адреса применить сканер сигнатур, но мне кажется есть другие пути.

Comment: А теперь получите адрес через GetProcAddress()

Comment: Получил, вернуло nullptr. Ну оно и понятно, функция не экспортная, просто глобальная.

Comment: Тогда придется признать, что оба варианта и с jmp, и с and ch, bl - верны, потому что функция может вызываться разными способами

Comment: Вызываться то да, но вот мне нужно именно иметь возможность знать где опкоды функции и соответственно редактировать их. Еще у меня был вариант как-то интерпретировать операнд инструкции JMP в адрес, что-то как-то поковырял, не вышло.

Comment: Думаю это сделал линкер. что бы не настраивать в куче мест адрес функции он положил в какую то фиксированную часть этот jmp и когда он знает реальный адрес функции, то правит только адрес в этом jmp. И да, у вас нет другого выхода кроме как интерпретировать самому jmp

Comment: Таки разобрался с операндом. Вся проблема была в том что байты записываются в обратном порядке. Сейчас буду пробовать реализовывать то что хотел.

Comment: Сейчас уже не помню всех деталей, давно про это читал. Но это такая особенность dll. Там создаётся такая таблица переходов, для удобства перенастройки адресов. И зачем вам адрес функции в dll? Всё равно там ничего нельзя поменять. Она лежит в shared read-only memory. Т.е. - доступна всем процессам.

Comment: @kisssko как это нельзя? Про VirtualProtect слышали?

Comment: @SNMetamorph В верхних адресах (выше 0x8000000) обычно винда не даёт менять права на память.